# Pact-python matching keys in response

Tags: python, matcher, pact

I am using pact-python (0.10.0), and want to verify the response from the provider. I am getting a response something like this:

```
"92c0ebfa-ffe5-4f4b-bfc4-ceb98063683f": {
    "2018-01-01T00:08:54+00:00": 270.0,
    "2018-01-01T02:09:29+00:00": 360.0
}
```

Is there a way I can verify the keys in the response (uuid and timestamps in this case). On using Matchers (Term or Like) I get json encoding error:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

Answer (score 0):

As of pact-python 0.10.0 it is not possible to apply matchers like `Term` and `Like` to the keys of an object. The complication lies in converting those values into JSON object keys to transmit to the mock service. Python complains the matchers are not hashable as they become Python `dicts` and JSON requires strings as object keys.

The Java implementation of Pact appears to support a type matcher using [eachKeyLike](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/313) that would assert it is a string but not a regex comparison, so it may be possible to extend pact-python to support something similar. My investigations so far make me think that change will require a little time to assemble.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, this is not currently supported by the underlying ruby code. You'd need to convert the python to use the Rust implementation via FFI bindings. Ron can give you some guidance on this.